# Parámetro Tabla por referencia

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Paso a explicarme:

- Tengo un Stored (`spXMLImportar`) que sólo lee un XML y devuelve esos datos en una tabla.
- Otros Store harán distintas cosas con la tabla devuelta por `spXMLImportar`.

Mi pregunta entonces es:

- ¿Cómo devuelvo los datos (por parámetro, tabla temporal, etc) desde **`spXMLImportar`** para que puedan ser manipulados desde otros Stored?

Comment: Si es una tabla definida en memoria, al final del store procedure bastara hacer un select sobre dicha tabla, podrias mostrar el store y los datos que quieres devolver.

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios tu problema realmente es otro. Si quieres manipular una tabla en varios procedimientos almacenados podrías trabajar con tablas temporales.

Comment: Puedes ver las respuestas a esta [pregunta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/209383/4092887) pero debes comprender bien las respuestas, algunas pueden que apliquen según tu versión de SQL Server. Si alguna de ellas soluciona tu inquietud, te recomiendo [responder a tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es devolver una tabla; basta con la ejecución del `SELECT [campos a devolver] FROM TABLA1 [demas tablas] [condiciones y demas instrucciones]`.

digamos que la última instrucción en tu storeprocedure debe ser el `select` con los datos a retornar.

Comment: Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta. El tema es que estaría necesitando devolverla en una variable porque tengo que trabajar con esos datos dentro del stored "inicial", que llamó al stored que devuelve la tabla. Espero explicarme bien.

Para ser más preciso, el stored importa desde un XML, y devuelve la tabla importada para poder seguir trabajando con esos datos desde donde se llamó originalmente.